# Using a function to create a new dataframe with unused elements

Tags: r, function, set-difference

I have two vectors with three elements.  There are twenty total combinations of taking all six elements and rearranging them into different sets of two vectors with three elements.  I need to write R code that will do that.

My current code sets the two vectors, combines them into one vector, creates a dataframe with all twenty combinations of a single vector of size three.  I'm now trying to write a function that will create the second vector of size three by comparing each of the twenty vectors to the vector with all elements, and seeing which elements are unused (setdiff).  However, I keep getting an empty new vector.  Please help.

```
drug<-c(36, 60, 39)
placebo<-c(73, 55, 70)
drugandplacebo<-c(drug,placebo)
drugandplacebo
number<-1:20
t(number)
allcombdrug<-combn(drugandplacebo,3)
allcombdrug
tallcombdrug<-t(allcombdrug)
tallcombdrug
tallcombdrub<-data.frame(tallcombdrub)
tallcombdrug

func1 <- function(tallcombdrug) {
  allcorespplac <- data.frame()  

  for (i in 1:length(tallcombdrug)) { 
    allcorespplac[i] <- setdiff(drugandplacebo,tallcombdrug[i])
  }
}
func1
allcorespplac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#list with all all combinations of three
l1 <- combn(c(drug, placebo),3,simplify = FALSE)
#list with all remaining values not in l1
l2 <- lapply(l1, function(x) c(drug,placebo)[!c(drug,placebo) %in% x])
```

**UPDATE: follow-up**

```
library(data.table)
cbind(
  data.table::rbindlist( lapply( l1, as.data.frame.list ) ),
  data.table::rbindlist( lapply( l2, as.data.frame.list ) )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Wimpel!.  A bit of a follow-up question (if I'm allowed to do that without asking another question from scratch:  I had to perform calculations with these two vectors and to do so, I used as.numeric.  I am now trying to combine all of these vectors into one big table, but when I list these two as columns, each value says "Numeric, 3" instead of each set of three elements.  I tried to use list(l1) to convert it back before putting it in the table but now it saws "List, 20."  What can I do so it will list each set of three?  Thanks!